# Listbox not showing in subform query (Access 2010)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a subform that is linked to a query. The query has several fields that are listboxes linked to other queries. The listboxes work as expected in the query itself, but once I use the query in a datasheet subform, the listbox functionality goes away and I am unable to pick from the dropdowns.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop the fields into the form in design view, and the lookup will follow. Well, *usually*.

If not, you must change the textbox on the form to a combobox and recreate the settings from the query.